# filter-branch that includes all commits of renamed files

Tags: git

Using `filter-branch` like explained [here](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) it's possible to split out some subdirectory to a new repository. However the suggested filter will only keep commits where the files in the directory had the same name/path as they do now.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME
```

I need a filter that will keep the same commits for each file as when doing `gitk --follow FILE-NAME`.

Essentially I need a filter that will keep commits for both the current filename/path and older filenames/paths for each file in the directory.

I tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- FOLDER-NAME' --prune-empty -- --all
```

but it did the same as `--subdirectory-filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own, fancy (perhaps very fancy), filter.

By this I don't mean *modify `git filter-branch` to add a new `--EJS-filter`*.  That *would* be one way to do it, but would require that you get ridiculously fancy. :-)  Instead, what I mean is this:

- Find the name(s) you want to preserve in particular commit range(s).

  This might be relatively easy: perhaps from commits "after" `a123456` onward, you keep all files named `newdirname/*`, and from commits "before" `a123456`, including `a123456` itself, you keep all files named `olddirname/*`.

  It might even be extremely easy: perhaps in commits after `a123456`, there *are no files named `olddirname/*`*, and in commits up to that point, there are no files named `newdirname/*`.  In this case, your filter devolves to: *Retain all files named `olddirname/*` or `newdirname/*`; remove all other files.*

  If it's not that easy, well, then it's not that easy.
- Now that you have identified which files to keep, write a `--tree-filter` (slow, but very easy to write) or `--index-filter` (much faster, but harder to write) that retains the files you want and deletes the files you don't want.

Here, you can (and maybe must) make use of the way that `git filter-branch` operates.  When you run `git filter-branch`, what Git does is:

1. Enumerate every commit reachable from the branch(es) you're filtering, according to whatever [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) style criteria you specify.  With just `--all` at the end, enumerate every commit reachable from every branch.
2. Put that list of commits into "reverse topological order", i.e., start with the *root* commit (the very first commit ever made) and then list its immediate children, then their children, and so on.  Hence for a commit chain that looks in part like this:

   ```
             G--H   <-- branch1
            /
   ...--E--F
            \
             I--J   <-- branch2
   ```

   the list would end with `E F` followed by either `G H I J` or `I J G H`.
3. For every commit in the list, do these steps (more or less):

   - check out the commit by its hash ID, saved temporarily in the variable `$GIT_COMMIT`;
   - run each `--whatever-filter`;
   - make a *new* commit from whatever's left;
   - update a map: "old `$GIT_COMMIT` becomes new hash ID just made".

   In other words, `git filter-branch` simply *copies* every commit.  With `--prune-empty` it skips the "make a new commit" step if the new commit would match its parent commit.

   In any case, the new commit's parent commit(s) is/are the *mapped* IDs.  That is, if we start from original commit `A`, which is a root commit and has no parents, we make a new commit `A'`:

   ```
   A--B--C--...

   A'   <-- (just made)
   ```

   Then we copy `B`, since that's the only child of `A`.  When we—through `git filter-branch`—make the new commit `B'` we make `B'`'s parent be `A'` rather than `A`:

   ```
   A--B--C--...

   A'-B'   <-- (just made)
   ```

   When we make `C'` from `C`, we'll have `B'` as its parent.  Or, if—due to the `--prune-empty` rule—we don't actually *make* `B'` after all, we'll set `C'`'s parent to `A'`.

What this means is that you can use `$GIT_COMMIT`, if necessary, to decide which file name(s) you wish to keep.  You can test it against all the existing commits in the repository, or build your own map of names to keep based on commit hashes, or whatever you like.

Note that in general, since you are dealing with a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of commit hashes, the test you usually want to use to implement these things is "is ancestor".  If commit *A* is an ancestor of commit *B*—more precisely, if *A ≼ B*, so that you allow for *A = B*—then you have a "before" situation.  This is what I described above: commits "before and including" `a123456` use an older name, while subsequent commits use a newer one.  The `git merge-base --is-ancestor A B` command performs this *A ≼ B* test, with its result delivered as a shell command exit status:

```
if git-merge-base --is-ancestor $GIT_COMMIT a123456; then ...; else ...; fi
```

tests whether `$GIT_COMMIT` ≼ `a123456`.